# Run python script without printing newline at end?

Tags: python

Whenever I run a python script, a new line is also printed at the end.

The only way I can stop this is by using posix._exit(0) at the end to avoid Python's cleanup code. Is there a more portable way?

(Sorry if this is a repeat question/seemingly obvious to answer. Unfortunately, I've only seen questions about printing without a newline)

Example script:

```
import os
#nothing actually done
```

Non-portable solution:

```
import os,posix
#nothing actually done
posix._exit()
```

OS: Windows
Tested with: Python in cygwin, native PyPy

Comment: Do you mean that you want to: '>python myscript.py' and get '>python myscript.py>' without the prompt moving to the next line?

Comment: @JoshRagem, kinda'. I effectively get two new lines, the one I typed to run the script, and the one from Python printing one. I want it just to move onto the next line, not to leave a blank line.

Comment: What operating system? Mine does not do that.

Comment: @JoshRagem, Sorry, I made a silly assumption that my test program with a single import and a completely empty script would be the same. Updated question.

Comment: Could be. I don't have any idea past that. Hope it isn't too big a bother to you.

Comment: Do you have something weird in your `$PYTHONRC` file? Mine doesn't do that either. Are you sure that there aren't any hidden print statements in `#nothing actually done`?

Comment: @quodlibetor, the new line is definitely printed after the script runs, which I think rules that out. (If it wasn't, posix._exit() wouldn't prevent it? :s) In any case, I don't have a pythonrc.

Comment: Then, unfortunately, I've got nothing. You do have a setup pretty far from my own, though--PyPy on cygwin is pretty far from CPython on Ubuntu.

Comment: On Ubuntu `pypy` doesn't write anything: `strace -e trace=write pypy -c "1"`

Comment: Have you tried `sys.exit(0)`?  That seems like it should be the portable way.

Comment: `os._exit(0)` should be portable

Comment: @steveha: `sys.exit()` does normal exit processing that the OP tries to avoid.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, thanks for the answer to my question.  I thought that might be the case but it seemed worth checking...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe is not normal python behavior, so something is probably odd about your setup. Try to debug it by stripping down what python does: Call python with `-E` (ignore environment options) and/or `-S` (don't load `site`). If that doesn't help, look at the other python invocation options for ideas, or try using a debugger.

Since `posix._exit(0)`, it's likely that something (in `site`?) is setting an exit handler that generates the newline. Look up `sys.exitfunc` and the module `atexit`, and check whether they're in use.

Answer (score 2):

This script may do what you want:

```
import sys

sys.stdout.write("Hello world")
```

The trick is to avoid using the built-in `print` statement.

Comment: Even with only 'import os' a new line is still printed by python.